# communication between Stellaris microcontroller and OSX

Tags: communication, microcontroller, uart

I'm trying to send sampled data from the Stellaris LM4F120 LaunchPad ([link](http://www.ti.com/tool/ek-lm4f120xl)) ADC to my host computer which runs OSX 10.6.8. First, I tried using the UART to send 4 bytes of data every 1.25 ms, which was the rate at which I collect data. I read these values via minicom running in the command line on the OSX side and printed to a text file. I tested out that I was correctly sampling signals with a 1 Hz input sine wave and when plotting the results, found that it was a 1.5 Hz sine wave which indicated that there was aliasing occuring. I think that the UART was not sending values to the host quickly enough which meant the microcontroller wasn't sampling as fast as I wanted it to.

I tried fixing this problem by creating a bigger data buffer and sending all the data at once. My problem with this is that the memory on the board can only hold about 32 kB and I need about 400 kB without any time lags in between.

I'm not really sure what to try next. I've heard that USB might work, but I don't know where to start with this path. Any advice on what direction to take next?. I'm new to working with microcontrollers, so I'm not sure what options I should be considering when improving the rate at which I can send data.

Comment: *"I tried using the UART to send 4 bytes of data every 1.25 ms"* - If your baud rate was greater than 32000 (e.g. 38400 or faster), then there should be enough time.  *"I think that the UART was not sending values to the host quickly enough which meant the microcontroller wasn't sampling as fast"* - Those are (or should be) two independent rates, so your conclusion is questionable.  You have not even mentioned how you programmed the UART speed, i.e. the baud rate.  If you haven't at least tried 115200 baud, then you have no business thinking about USB.

Comment: How are you interleaving the collection and transmission of data? Are there any interrupts or everything is done in a loop?
Without interrupts and DMA, you may be spending too much time in wait states. I agree with the above comment, try reducing the ADC sampling time and increasing the UART baud-rate.